# GenomicRanges Error loading DESeq2 library on R

Tags: r, genomicranges

I tried to loading DESeq2 on R:
`library(DESeq2)`

The Error showed is:

```
Loading required package: GenomicRanges
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘GenomicRanges’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 object 'vI' not found
Error: package ‘GenomicRanges’ could not be loaded


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] GenomeInfoDb_1.22.1 IRanges_2.21.8      S4Vectors_0.25.15  
[4] BiocGenerics_0.32.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.11        zlibbioc_1.32.0        R6_2.4.1              
 [4] fansi_0.4.1            tools_3.6.3            pkgbuild_1.0.6        
 [7] cli_2.0.2              withr_2.1.2            remotes_2.1.1         
[10] assertthat_0.2.1       rprojroot_1.3-2        crayon_1.3.4          
[13] processx_3.4.2         GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.2 BiocManager_1.30.10   
[16] callr_3.4.3            bitops_1.0-6           ps_1.3.2              
[19] RCurl_1.98-1.1         curl_4.3               glue_1.4.0            
[22] compiler_3.6.3         backports_1.1.6        prettyunits_1.1.1
```

I blocked since 2 days. All the problem start for "S4Vectors" package. I solved it. I update the R. I donwloaded and manually put in the library r folder the "XVector" version ‘0.27.2’ as required from GenomicRanges. 
I need to use DESeq2 to normalize my cont data. I open to use also something different from r

Comment: hey i think your r version is a bit too new, the bioconductor packages might not be up to date.. any chance of using R 3.6.2 ? Otherwise might have to manage the dependencies one by one..

Comment: Thanks for replying,  "any chance of using R 3.6.2 ?" Yes, I can if you think this could be the problem. Could be a "disagreement" between macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and R 3.6.2 ?

Comment: Don't think so... although your mac OS is... ancient... I don't know, because so far i have only 3.6.1 and 3.6.2

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I fixed the problem uninstalled and re-installed all the R library from my PC keeping the same OS and R version. I continue to ignore the real identity of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem simply by removing the "GenomicRanges" and "IRange" packages and installing "GenomicRanges" again.
To remove these packages I used `.libPaths()` to find the library path and removed GenomicRanges" and "IRange" folders.